# Stood in front of microwave with the door open

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, everyday-life, estimation, biology, microwaves

I was cooking something in the microwave and opened the door early to check on it and the microwave didn't stop. I didn't realize this for a few seconds and when I did I shut the microwave off but I'm concerned what I could have been exposed to for the few seconds that it was open.

As far as I can remember I still heard the humming and the light was on so I assume it was still running. I didn't think it was even possible for it to keep running with the door open. The microwave is a fairly new model as well.

Is there radiation or other things that could have caused some damage in those few seconds?

Comment: If you were close enough for long enough you could get a burn. But you don’t have to worry about the type of cell damage that can occur with gamma rays or something. Microwave radiation is lower energy than lots of other radiation you’re exposed to all the time, like sunlight.

Comment: This should not be possible. The danger is primarily to the eyes, because they get heated by microwaves. There is no blood circulating in the vitreous humor to transport the heat away. And you would not feel it. But also that heating takes some time.

Comment: @Pieter that was my biggest concern after doing some research but I wasn't sure if I should get checked out after those few seconds.

Comment: Personally I would not worry about this unless you keep your head inside the microwave for more than a few minutes. It is microwave, not X-ray.

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment, because it's not about physics. Last time it happened to me, it was the office microwave. Someone set it on "combined" mode (which means it was both microwaving and grilling). I thought it kept running, when in fact it wasn't (a colleague explained it's the ventilation from the grill mode, which keeps the light and the sound going). I don't know whether or not you are in the same situation, but I thought I would drop it here.

Comment: Not an answer but go online and search for the exact same make and model. Try adding different words to the search such as "problem". The chances are that someone else will have the same question. It's worth checking that there isn't a manufacturer's recall notice on the model as well.

Comment: My combined oven+microwave sometimes does keep the light on and keeps humming for several minutes after either I open the door or let the timer finish. I say "sometimes" because for short durations (less than 90s) both the light and the humming turn off immediately. It must be some self-cooling mechanism that triggers only above a certain usage time.

Comment: It could have interfered with radio astronomy.

Comment: oh my god stop using it any more the radiation from the magnetron can harm your eyes and "balls" since blood circulation can't carry excess heat as fast... I don't know medical stuff but your sperms probably wouldn't get heatstroke from brief exposure ;D

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics

Comment: Your best bet is to call the manufacturer's customer service line and ask them. They will know best what exactly is possible with their model.

Comment: Related: ["Microwave starts working when door opens - how dangerous is it?"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/437053/) at SE.ElectricalEngineering.

Comment: Warning: A high-rep moderator at SE.ElectricalEngineering [stressed that this could be a dangerous situation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/437053/437109#437109).

Comment: @Nat, RF burns can be nasty because they go _deep_. But, if OP were burned, they would already know it by now..

Comment: My microwave "operates" with the door open. It operates the lights and and the fan, which of course makes a humming sound.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The very first thing you should do is stop using your oven and have it checked out by an authorized repair service.

If in fact the oven was operating with the door open, there was a failure of the door interlocks to turn the oven off and a failure of the backup system intended to permanently shut the oven off in the event the interlocks failed which, although extremely unlikely, is nonetheless possible.

The next thing you need to know is that microwave "radiation" is not the same thing as x-radiation, gamma rays, or other forms of nuclear radiation, which are referred to as "ionizing radiation" and are associated with injury such as cancer if excessive. Microwave radiation is non-ionizing radiation which, to date, has only been conclusively associated with thermal injury, i.e., injury to tissue due to heating (that's how it cooks food).

Since you were only potentially exposed for a few seconds, unless you are experiencing discomfort, you are probably all right since the temperature of your tissue was probably not raised all that much. In the early days of commercial microwave ovens, before multiple safety features were required, there were incidents where workers were exposed to multiple exposures and had some loss of muscle function due to heating damage. But those were the cumulative effects of many exposures. A few seconds of exposure is unlikely to cause that effect on you.

In any case, I urge you to stop using your oven now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It may be that the light, turntable, and fan were running, but the magnetron was not firing.  I recently disassembled a late model microwave and there were no less than three independent microswitches physically disconnecting power to the magnetron transformer that were only able to all be closed if the door was closed and locked.

Comment: @Tristan That certainly is possible, which is why I carefully chose my words to say "If in fact the oven was operating with the door open". But why take a chance. It was nearly 40. years ago when I tested microwave ovens for safety. Then there were two independent interlock switches and a separate monitor, called a crowbar circuit, that would blow an internal fuse if one or both of the interlock switches were closed with the door open. The interlock safety system has probably evolved since then.

Comment: It took me a little while to realize it, but my last roommate's microwave will keep the fan running for a while if the microwave was used for more than 2 minutes. It sounded like it was still running when it wasn't. I finally confirmed what was going on by reading the sticker inside the door, which stated the expected fan behavior

Comment: @anjama It seemed to me a bad design that would permit things to run with the door open because one might think the oven was operating when it is not, especially if the turntable keeps turning.  The oven you refer to probably keeps the fan on for a while to eliminate any steam/moisture in the oven. The sticker you refer to shows the manufacturer was aware the user might think the oven was running because the fan was on.

Comment: @BobD I suspect the evolution has been in the direction of lower cost (maintaining adequate safety for regulatory purposes), not higher safety

Comment: My combination (also oven and grill) microwave runs a fan at various time when it's not emitting, as well as various other humming noises.  It has been known to turn the turntable  when it shouldn't (controller crashed, had to reboot with the wall switch), but it wasn't heating - I'd have noticed when I reached in

Comment: @Chris H the combination microwave/conventional oven is a whole other matter. There are good reasons for operating fans to facilitate the conventional cooking functions

Comment: @BobD, of course, and to cool the electronics with a big heating element nearby. We don't know whether the OP has a simple microwave or one like mine, which was why I thought a passing mention might be worthwhile

Comment: In either case, the microwave oven needs a specific sized cavity to focus any microwave heat in. If the door is open I doubt you'd get anything else than a discomfort at arms length (unless you, resolute in the decision to get horribly burned, stood there tanking it, for way longer than your sensory system told you was wise)

Comment: @Tristan My current microwave oven seems to be designed somewhat like that.  I've been having issues where it will appear to be running (fan, turntable) but doesn't heat anything.  I have close (slam) the door and listen for the signature hum.

Comment: @StianYttervik Need to be careful here. In the incident I referred to in my answer the persons were putting in and taking out food while the oven was operating without really any discomfort. They didn't realize they were undergoing cumulative tissue damage until they started losing muscle function. At that point, it was too late.

Comment: @Tristan, Jimmy James, Chris and all. In order to know what is the correct and incorrect operation of the oven one needs to read the manufacturer's use and care instructions.

Comment: @BobD you're right there - if the OP had provided the make and model we wouldn't be need to speculate (though the manuals for many models wouldn't tell you if it carried  on humming with the door open)

Comment: As I understand, the main risk of microwave thermal damage is to the eyes because the blood vessels are so small

Comment: @Gimmethe411 Yes, the eyes are very vulnerable because of their inability to dissipate heat. As a matter of fact, as I recall the conservative microwave leakage limits were, in part, set realizing that. As I recall, experiments on rabbit eyes showed cataracts at 100 mw/cm$^2$. Back in my time, oven limits set by the FDA were 1 mw/cm$^2$ brand new and 5 mw/cm$^2$ over the life of the oven measured a few centimeters from any outer surface of the oven. These are very conservative regarding general heating of the body considering magnitude of the EM drops rapidly moving away from the oven.

Answer (score 22):

When reading your post, it seemed to me that the most likely explanation for your experience is that the microwave did turn off, but the ventilation did not. You may have mistaken this for the microwave not turning off.

If indeed the microwave didn't turn off, you would have felt pain and other sensations immediately. Get a new microwave in that case, and throw out the old one.

Edit: With other effects, I was referring to the discoveries of Allan Frey. Also, being exposed directly to a couple of hundreds of Watts is a different story than your local wifi. The heat will be felt immediately. The frequencies are also selected to penetrate food including meat and human tissue. This would be very unpleasant soon.

Comment: No, one would not feel pain. Not until it the microwaves had overheated some tissue. Our heat receptors are almost all in the skin.

Comment: I would expect to feel heat, not pain (agreeing with @Pieter).  A microwave oven puts out a few hundred Watts of microwave radiation.  An infrared heater puts out a few hundred Watts of radiation at shorter wavelengths, and can be felt quite strongly and immediately from a couple of metres away.  The microwave penetration depth is probably greater than for IR (less heating where the nerve endings are), but the OP was probably about half a metre away.  That said I suspect it was humming but not emitting, so +1.

Comment: ... I'd test the power consumption when I open the door with it running because I have a mains power meter and more curiosity than fear.  It should drop from ~1kW to a few W as fast as the power meter can update.

Comment: Don't throw out old appliances! Donate them to a recycler or your local neighbourhood hackerspace. They may be able to repair it or turn the parts into something else. Do put a big sticker saying the safety interlock is broken though. Throwing things out in the landfill is a waste of natural resources.

Comment: While I do not agree with the second part (which is simply wrong), the first one makes a lot of sense, especially if it is a new microwave OP bought. My microwave makes basically the same sound when open because of the cooling (and it says `Cool` on the display)

Comment: @user253751 I've just seen your comment about not throwing out old appliances. While I agree with you with respect to run of the mill appliances, the idea of donating a microwave oven appliance, or any other appliance,  that clearly may be hazardous, to a possible unsuspecting  "recycler or your local neighborhood hackerspace", a big warning sticker not withstanding, horrifies me as a 40+ year safety engineer. The risk of someone maybe tying to use such a product is far greater than the risk of a "waste of natural resources". Just my opinion of course.

Comment: @Pieter Re your comment,  multiple thumbs up!

Comment: @BobD Well, for example, the *metal box* could be reused for something. DIYers should know when they're doing something dangerous. Plenty of reasonably safe stuff you could salvage from a microwave. Fan, turntable motor, big metal box, LCD display... big transformer and capacitor (*if you know what you're doing*). If you are salvaging components you should know what you're doing. Otherwise *all* DIY projects must scare you. If you're afraid of someone picking up the microwave and using it as-is in their kitchen, cut the power cord off so they can't (as well as the sticker/note).

Comment: @user253751 Like I said, it’s just my opinion and I feel no need to defend it. Likewise your entitled to your opinion as well.

Comment: (Also most people don't know any hackerspace that wants their appliance, so recycler is the default option)

Answer (score 11):

I mentioned this in a comment, but will post as an answer as well.

Apparently, if you run it long enough, some microwaves will keep the fan running for cooling even though the microwave is no longer producing microwaves. My last roommate's microwave did this at the 2 minute mark, and even though the microwave was done cooking, the running fan made it sound like it still was running.

You should be able to confirm the behavior by looking in the owner's manual that came with it (or looking up the manual for your model online). Alternatively, the behavior may be described on one of the stickers on the microwave itself (which was the case with my former roommate's microwave). The sticker may be on the back of the machine, or it may be placed along the frame hidden by the door when it's closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find the info on a sticker on the product or in a manual online...

**Call the manufacturer and ask**

Call their customer service and tell them what you observed. They will either tell you that A) it was expected behavior because e.g. as others have suggested the fan keeps running for ventilation after running it a while, or B) that there may have been a significant safety failure, and you should stop using it. In the case latter case they may be able to advise you on the likelihood that you suffered personal injury.

Bottom line is they will know your model best, and have skin in the game when it comes to your safety, so while the other answers provide good general advice, they will be best able to advise you with regard to your specific model.

And until you clear this up, I'd stop using it. Just in case.

Comment: *may be able to advise you on the likelihood that you suffered personal injury* In today's litigious society, I highly doubt that. The customer service people (who are not management/top/etc.) are almost certainly told to **not** say: "You might be injured" because that would them up to a lawsuit and **not** say "You're fine" because if you were injured then they would have that "disinformation" added to the lawsuit. So they'll be nice and certainly tell you if it is a feature (cooling fan), but otherwise, if out-of-warranty, probably just tell you to replace it.

Comment: True. I considered that--so most likely they'd comment on the product, and you'd have to read between the lines.